# how to extract controllers and views from the pre-built app in the Ionic framework?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

In an Ionic App, the directory structure shows

[App structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioRRE.png)

In the

> www > scripts > app.js

is a JavaScript file that holds all the code of the controllers and the views inside it. Only changes that are reflected in the browser are the ones that are made in this file.

The controllers and views in the directory structure are not working with anything as any change made in the them does not reflect in the app and their entire code in the app.js file gives the changes we need. entire app is running from one file?

How to make it so that the changes made in the directory structure files are reflected in the app and is the app.js file needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controllers and views in the directory structure are not working with any change made in the them because it is already a built app. and you are trying to edit the code which is not accessible to run the app.

First, check app is built-up with **gulp** command. If yes then you have to use command:

> gulp --tasks

It will show all the existing tasks which are running under gulp. Now run the command

> gulp default

Using this you can check the changes applied in controllers on the app.